# D function returning zero

Tags: r, maximize, log-likelihood

I am attempting to differentiate the log likelihood function of a multivariate normal distribution,

```
NLLmvnorm <- function(data, mu, sigma) {
  a <- qr(sigma)
  logdet <- sum(log(abs(diag(a$qr))))
  sigma.inv <- fast.ginv(sigma)
  -0.5 * (logdet + t(data-mu) %*% sigma.inv %*% (data-mu))
}
```

Using `D`, I differentiate with respect to `mu` and `sigma` and store each result in a separate variable:

```
du <- D(expression(NLLmvnorm),"mu")
ds <- D(expression(NLLmvnorm),"sigma")
```

However, both of these results return `0`. Am I doing something incorrect, or am I misinterpreting what `D` does? If it helps, my goal is to find the roots of `du` and `ds` to find maximum likelihood using `solve`.

Comment: See the help page, `?D`, the last paragraph before section `Value`. Your function is not among the functions `D` knows.

Comment: I see, so the only way to go about this is manually calculate the derivative and then plug that formula into R?

Comment: Yes, it is. But there are solvers that don't need the gradient, such as `optimise`.